# Instagram : Client_id redirect me to a page not found

Tags: oauth, instagram

I'm working on an xcode app that interact with instagram, I use to create client_id and test them and it worked just fine, but lately the new client_id redirect me to a page not found screen :

https://instagram.com/oauth/authorize?response_type=token&redirect_uri=[REDIRECT_URI]&scope=comments+likes&client_id=[CLIENT_ID]#

I appreciate your help.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

It seems like what your using is out dated. Try this: https://instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=CLIENT-ID&redirect_uri=REDIRECT-URI&response_type=token

Try using explicit (server side) auth, I find it more reliable plus the limits are increased.
http://instagram.com/developer/authentication/